# How to get the row or columns of two dimensional array

Tags: c#

I am wondering how to get the row of the two dimensional array like

int[3,3] a = ****

I tried a[0], but it failed. anyway to get the rwo array?

Comment: I would like to get the first row as an array?

Comment: you may want to use jagged arrays like int[][] a

Comment: `a[0,0]` is the 2-d equivalent of `a[0]`

Answer (score 3):

Two-dimensional array is not array of arrays. If you want to get 'row', then you need to get all items from array which have same value of some dimension. E.g. if you are getting all values from first dimension:

```
int[,] array = new int[4, 3] { 
      { 1, 2, 3 },
      { 4, 5, 6 },
      { 7, 8, 9 },
      { 10, 11, 12 }
   };

for(int i = 0; i <= array.GetUpperBound(1); i++)
    Console.WriteLine(array[0,i]); // getting all items from first dimension
```

You can put all these items to array:

```
int rowIndex = 0;
int[] row = Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetUpperBound(1) + 1)
                      .Select(i => array[1, i])
                      .ToArray();
```

Another option will be using jagged-array instead of two-dimensional array:

```
int[][] array = new []{ 
   new[] { 1, 2, 3 },
   new[] { 4, 5, 6 },
   new[] { 7, 8, 9 },
   new[] { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }
};
```

It's an array of arrays. But note that inner arrays can have different size. Getting some 'row' will look like

```
int[] row = array[0];
```